# Is there a Firebase analytics API?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Is there an API for getting access to the data from Firebase analytics for my app? I would like to get programmatic access to users by country so that I can display it on my site but I have not found a way to do it.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) gives programmatic access to users by country.

In Data API requests, you'll need to identify your Google Analytics 4 (GA4) property by it's ID; this ID is different from the Firebase project. This [page on Property ID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/property-id#firebase) shows how to find your GA4 property ID.

There are example requests of users by country in the [Creating a Report Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics#report_request).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Brett. Is this the same "analytics" that I see in the Firebase console? You don't happen to know if there is an Angular SDK for it?